# Converting HTML Number to Date Format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I create a table by pulling data into the web application with the following code. The dates in the first column of the table ("r [0]") come to the number format. How can I convert the number format to date format as below?
Number: 44346
To: 30.05.2021 or 30.05.2021 - 23:59:10

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getTableData(username);

function generateTable(dataArray)
{
      var tbody = document.getElementById("table-body");

        dataArray.forEach(function(r){  

        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        for(i=0; i<14; i++) {
              var col = document.createElement("td");
              col.textContent = r[i];
              row.appendChild(col); 
        }
        if(r[13] == "ONAYLANDI")
              row.style.backgroundColor = "#0EE600";
        tbody.appendChild(row);
  });
}
```

Comment: I understand that 44346 means 30.05.2021 - 23:59:10 but can you specify what exactly your 44346 represents and why is it corresponding to the date you have shown?

Comment: It pulls the table data from "Google Sheets". The table contains values with date and text. When I convert the date column to date format, it does not show the data in the table. But when converted to number format, it shows in the table. That's why I need to convert the number values I draw from "Google Sheets" to date in the "HTML" page.

Google Sheets: 44346
HTML Web Page: 30.05.2021

Comment: If you just want to add a date-formatted string to your HTML table, you could just transform the date you retrieve from the spreadsheet to a properly formatted string, no need to convert it to a number format. Can you provide more information about how data is formatted in the sheet and how you are retrieving it from there?

Comment: Halit, please, show your source table. It's still not clear to me how you managed to get `43346` from `30.05.2201` or whatever you had in the column in original table. If you had a text date in the table, you can try to leave the data as a text string. No need to convert it into numbers or date on that stage.

Answer (score 1):

When I convert it to date format like in the image, it does not show the table data on the Web page. The codes related to data extraction are as follows.

[image]

```
// MACRO PAGE

function getTableData(username) {

        var vs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nRGsoyU70SZ7CwZKzHBhHEA92PhllqnsStpTPgocd3Q/').getSheetByName('Rapor GEÇMİŞ');
  var data = vs.getRange(2, 1,vs.getLastRow()-1, 14).getValues().reverse().filter(function(item)  {  return item[7]=== username;   });
  console.log("Başarılı "+username);
return data;


}

// JS PAGE
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getTableData(username);

function generateTable(dataArray)
{
      var tbody = document.getElementById("table-body");

        dataArray.forEach(function(r){  

        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        for(i=0; i<14; i++) {
              var col = document.createElement("td");
              col.textContent = r[i];
              row.appendChild(col); 
        }
        if(r[13] == "ONAYLANDI")
              row.style.backgroundColor = "#0EE600";
              
        tbody.appendChild(row);
  });
}
```

Web page result

[image]

When I convert the date to text format, it displays it on the web page (For example, text format "20.05.2021"). But when I convert it to date format as a numeric expression, it doesn't show. (For example number format "44336", date format "20.05.2021")

Comment: Why do you need to convert them into date format at all? You can get a string "20.05.2021" and you can put in HTML table the same string "20.05.2021". What else you do need? To get the dates from Google table as text strings you need to use `getDisplayValues()` instead of `getValues()`

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer?

Comment: To sort from A to Z, I have to convert the number format to date format. For display purposes only.

Comment: Consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on. As Yuri said, use `getDisplayValues()` instead of `getValues()` to retrieve the date string (if that's how it's displayed in the spreadsheet). And consider removing this answer, since this is not an answer, and add whatever information is included in it to your question, where it belongs.